# Error code E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) when installing shim-signed

Tags: dpkg

```
$ sudo apt-get install shim-signed
[sudo] password for patwines: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
shim-signed is already the newest version (1.32~16.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm4.0 linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-26 linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-26-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-26-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.66.15+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15) ...
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up shim-signed (1.32~16.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
patwines@patwines-Lenovo-G700:~$ 

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try to reinstall `grub-pc-bin` package with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc-bin` to fix missing `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh` file. And `sudo apt-get install -f` following by `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.